# Proving $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}$ does not exist, using epsilon-delta

Tags: limits

> I have to prove that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}$$
> does not exist, using epsilon-delta.

My attempt: We first consider left hand limit. Let $\varepsilon$ be given.

Now, choosing $\delta=\varepsilon/2$

$$\left|\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1)-1}\right|=2\left|\frac{e^{1/x}}{e^{1/x}+1}\right| <2x <2\delta< \varepsilon$$

Is this correct? And I have no clue how to prove right hand limit. I know it is 1, but how do I prove with epsilon-delta method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality choose $0< \epsilon <1$ and take $\delta =[\ln(\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1)]^{-1}>0$. If $x \in (-\delta,0)$

\begin{align}
&x > - \left[\ln \left(\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1 \right)\right]^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x} < -\ln \left(\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1 \right) \\
&\Rightarrow - \frac{1}{x} > \ln \left(\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1 \right) \\
&\Rightarrow e^{- \frac{1}{x}} > \frac{2}{\epsilon}-1 \\
&\Rightarrow 1+e^{- \frac{1}{x}}>\frac{2}{\epsilon} \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{2}{1+e^{- \frac{1}{x}}}<\epsilon \\
&\Rightarrow \left|\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}-(-1)\right|=\frac{2e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}<\epsilon
\end{align}
This shows that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0-}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}\right)=-1$. By taking the same $\delta$ it can be shown that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}\right)=1$. Since the two limits aren't equal $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1}\right)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take care about the following
$
\lim_{x\to 0-}
$
and
$
\lim_{x\to 0+}
$

Detials:
$\lim_{x\to0+ }e^{\frac 1x} = \infty$ but $\lim_{x\to 0-} e^{\frac 1x } = 0$ , so
$$\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1} = -1$$ but
$$\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1} = 1$$

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? I don't get it. Thanks

Comment: Okay... but how do I prove that by epsilon delta method?  And is my attempt correct?Thanks